# Is there a way to reduce the size of a React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I use `npx create-react-app my-app` and it downloads quickly. Then it installs and it lasts way too long, an hour or more. Then I go into the folder that I just installed and the `node_modules` folder is too big, it is 4.24 GB of size.

Is this normal? When I copy and paste the React project that I installed to create a new project it also lasts too long, I think due to how many files the `node_modules` folder has. Again it's close to an hour.

I feel this is not a good way of starting projects. It is way too time consuming, populates the whole space in my disk and takes all the disk power to that specific task.

I was wondering if there's a way to have a minified version of the project or something. Some way to not have to go through this every time I have to create a new project.

I don't know if this question is too abstract but if every time that I want to start a new project I have to use 4GB of space and spend an hour copying or installing the different modules, depending on whether I used the command or straight up copied and pasted the folder, it's both a waste of time and memory when I haven't even started coding yet.

Comment: One option is not to use CRA - it sets up a lot of things for you, but that's the tradeoff, it installs a lot of dependencies you may not actually need. That might not be worth making if you're on such constrained hardware and networking.

Comment: Mine doesn't go above 20MB how you go above 4GB?

Comment: node_modules weights 4gb for me using create-react-app

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few leads:

1. Don't use CRA. Create your app from scratch with webpack and babel (or other similar tools)
2. Only install necessary npm packages. Avoid ui-libs, and all the fuss you could easily write yourself in js.
3. Code-split your routes and components.
4. Write re-usable code and components.
5. Use efficient performance tools with webpack such as Terser plugin.